# Glazed Lists EventTableModel class stroked in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable, glazedlists

I try to use Glazed List to create dinamically changed TableModel. All works fine, but class name EventTableModel is written strikethrough text (I use NetBeans IDE). I watch class implementation - no @Deprecated annotation here. Has anyone encountered this problem? What does this mean? I downloaded latest binary .jar from here: [download page](http://java.net/projects/glazedlists/downloads/directory/latest_build)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't chack the right implementation, I just downloaded the source from the link you provided, I can see the following, excerpted from `EventTableModel` javadoc:

```
* @deprecated Use {@link DefaultEventTableModel} instead. This class will be removed in the GL
*             2.0 release. The wrapping of the source list with an EDT safe list has been
*             determined to be undesirable (it is better for the user to provide their own EDT
*             safe list).
```

so you just have to follow the indication there and use `DefaultEventTableModel` instead.